# sum of all rows of the query result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

```
Select (sum(OS.Small) + sum(OS.Medium)) * T.ColorPrice as TotalPrice
from Order_Colors OC
left outer join Order_Selection OS on OS.Order_ColorID = OC.Order_ColorID 
left outer join TShirtPrices T on T.Order_ColorID = OS.Order_ColorID
left outer join OrderInfo O on O.OrderID = OS.OrderID 
where O.CID = 1025
group by OC.Order_ColorID, OC.Color, O.OrderID, T.ColorPrice, T.TShirtPurchaseID
```

This query gives me 1 column "Total Price" with around 20 rows. I am looking to get the sum of all these rows in the same sql query. Is it possible in MS SQL 2005?

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I tried but i get the group by error for the column T.Colorprice

Comment: @bluefeet Its the MS SQL 2005

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server you can use [`ROLLUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
Select (sum(OS.Small) + sum(OS.Medium)) * T.ColorPrice as TotalPrice
from Order_Colors OC
left outer join Order_Selection OS 
    on OS.Order_ColorID = OC.Order_ColorID 
left outer join TShirtPrices T 
    on T.Order_ColorID = OS.Order_ColorID
left outer join OrderInfo O 
    on O.OrderID = OS.OrderID 
where O.CID = 1025
group by OC.Order_ColorID, OC.Color, O.OrderID, T.ColorPrice, T.TShirtPurchaseID with ROLLUP
```

This will give you the `Total Price` with for row and then you will also get a final Total of all values.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the `GROUP BY` part of your query and you will get one result.

Comment: yes, i tried doing that but i get the group by clause error for T.ColorPrice :-(

Comment: @Ram huh? You should not have any issues... I have no idea why that would be happening.

Comment: @Neal they are use sql server so since they are using `colorprice` in the select it has to be in the `group by`

Comment: I will just add it up using Asp.Net! But i would love to know why i couldn't do it in SQL server though!

Comment: @Ram Did you try the `rollup` answer I gave?